# XML/XSL output as CSS background-image url()

Tags: css, xml, xslt, svg

**How can I use XSL output from XML resource inside CSS url() function?**

I have an XSL file transforming an XML file into an SVG output through the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt-file.xsl"?>` tag (in the XML).

If I go to the XML's URI, the XML is transformed, and the resulting SVG is displayed.

Now, I want this SVG output to be used in a CSS `background-image: url('source.xml');` property, but looks like the XSL transform does not occur: no background is displayed. 
The document that uses this background and the XML/XSL are all on the same domain.

**How can I use the result of an XSL/XML transform on the CSS background-image property and url() function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the browser will require that the svg image file is served with the correct MIME type.  Ie.:

```
Content-type: image/svg+xml
```

It won't be in your case.  This step isn't necessary when viewed standalone because the browser will figure it out.

You'll need to configure your webserver to serve those particular XML files with that content type.  However it is possible that this may interfere with the XSL processing. I'm not sure.

Comment: The browser sends the HTTP header "Accept": "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5" and serveur responds with a "Conte-Type" of "application/xml", shouldn't it be accepted because of "*/*"?

I tried to fool the browser, and put my XML data into a SVG file, but I still don't figure out how to apply the XSL on that XML file (whether it's send as real application/xml or as a fake image/svg+xml").

Comment: My point is that the browser isn't accepting application/xml as an image type. And as I suspected, the browser won't apply the XSL if it sees a content type of image/svg+xml.  I guess you might have to do the XSL processing on the server side.